# PL/SQL: Access view of different user in Stored Procedure

Tags: plsql, view, sql-grant

Good afternoon,

I have 2 users in an ORACLE database, USER1 and USER2.

USER2 has a view VIEW1, and i want a procedure in USER1 to access VIEW1 through a cursor, like this:

```
    create or replace procedure PROCEDURE1   is
        CURSOR C_CURSOR
        IS

        select * from USER2.VIEW1;

      BEGIN
        RETURN; 
   end PROCEDURE1;
```

However, when i try to compile the PROCEDURE1, i get the error:

ORA-01031 - insufficient privelieges

However, i only get this error inside the stored procedure, as i can do the following query just fine from USER1:

```
select * from USER2.VIEW1;
```

Can you please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: USER1 must have been granted access indirectly, via a role.  To create the procedure it needs the explicit privilege `grant select on user2.view1 to user1;`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had tried that before, but i could'nt because USER2.VIEW1 was selecting from a table of a 3rd USER, USER3. I finally got it by granting select on the table from USER3 to USER2 with grant option.

Answer (score 0):

See Tony Andrews comment on the question.

> USER1 must have been granted access indirectly, via a role. To create
>   the procedure it needs the explicit privilege grant select on
>   user2.view1 to user1; – Tony Andrews Aug 16 '17 at 16:01

(no I'm not fishing for reputation; I just want this to drop out of the unanswered queue)